# Tap to click working for one bot not the other user

Tags: touchpad, kde

I have two users on my new Kubuntu installation. For the first clicking via touchpad does not work. I've created a new user and for that one, without me doing anything else, it works just fine.

Any ideas how this can be and how I can get it to work for my first user as well? Scrolling with two fingers on the touchpad works.

I have it enabled in the settings:

[image: touchpad taps settings]

Here's the output of `synclient -l`:

```
LeftEdge                = 143
RightEdge               = 3448
TopEdge                 = 101
BottomEdge              = 1780
FingerLow               = 0
FingerHigh              = 0
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 179
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 80
HorizScrollDelta        = 83
VertEdgeScroll          = 1
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0493462
TouchpadOff             = 2
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 2
RBCornerButton          = 3
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 3
TapButton3              = 2
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 1
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.10472
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 0
TapAndDragGesture       = 0
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 20
VertHysteresis          = 20
ClickPad                = 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately deleting `~/.kde/share/config` didn't do the trick. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: No it didn't cause any headache, thanks. It was worth a try!

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. What did do the trick in the end - all of a sudden - was going into the touchpad settings shown above and simply restoring the defaults... although it didn't change anything I could see. Oh well. In any case it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing the 'Defaults' button, which you can see in the screenshot, did the trick.